# Expose viewmodel to draw a bar using WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, mvvm

I'm building a WPF user control which displays a simple stacked bar using `Rectangle`s. The data is provided by a `DependencyProperty` in the viewmodel so I can bind a collection to it. The model looks like this:

```
public class BarPart {
  public Color Color { get; set; }
  public int Size { get; set; }
}
```

The view with a fake width binding illustrating the intent:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=Root, Path=Data}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Rectangle Width="{Binding TotalSize / Size * Root.Width}" Height="30">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Color}" />
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Of course the size is not in a unit used for display, it can be any number. This means I can't bind directly to `Size`. Yet the total width of the stacked bars should span the width of the usercontrol. The bound size should be calculated using the sum of the sizes, the size of the BarPart in question, and the total width of the control.

MVVM dictates the viewmodel shouldn't know anything about the view. So where should these calculations and conversions take place?

An `IValueConverter` can't do the math since it doesn't know the *sum* of all BarPart sizes  combined and doesn't know the total width of the usercontrol to convert to display units.

I'm not sure what other options I have doing strict MVVM.

Comment: `DependencyProperty in the viewmodel` - [DependencyProperties Don't belong into ViewModels](http://kentb.blogspot.com.ar/2009/03/view-models-pocos-versus.html)

Comment: @HighCore Thanks for pointing that out, that's a bad decision on my part. But going POCO still won't solve the problem I laid out. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Odd, but I had to do this *exact* problem except that the domain was market liquidity.  The control had a liquidity context which the VM binded to, and the control did the percentage calculations.  But that was because each rectangle had to have a tool tip and etc etc...

Comment: @GarryVass What do you mean by 'context the VM binded to'? Could you maybe show a snippet of code?

Comment: The code itself is in the proprietary domain, but I could post a lightweight example of how it works; Is that likely to be acceptable as an answer for your question though?

Comment: I think the MultiBinding does what I need. Thanks anyway Garry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `MultiBinding` with converter, bindings would be something like:

```
<Binding Path="Size"/>
<Binding ElementName="Root" Path="DataContext.TotalSize"/>
<Binding ElementName="Root" Path="ActualWidth"/>
```

The view model containing the bars should calculate the `TotalSize`.

(To keep it updated you need to subscribe to property changes on all the bars so that you can fire a property changed event for `TotalSize` if the `Size` of any bar changes. Of course if bars are added/removed that also needs to be done.)